# How to change XCode Default storyboard Ipad to Iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My OS version is OS X Version 10.9.4.
XCode Version is 6.0.1

Everytime I create a new project ,the storyboard is always for ipad even I choose Device to iphone.The old projects with iphone storyboard work fine.But Everytime I create a new project whatever I choose ,it is always ipad storyboad.Please help me!

Comment: with XCode 6; it's not an iPad storyboard; it's a size-class based layout. Please read up on how [the new system works](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html), as it should give you a better understanding of what it's trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it programmatically

```
NSString *storyName = @"MainStoryboard_iPhone";

 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     storyName = @"MainStoryboard_iPad";
 }

UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

or made by default the storyboard on your settings projects. On General, deployment target, main interface, switch between iPhone / iPad

Answer (score 0):

On xCode 7: select the View Controller, click on Attributes Inspector at the top of the Utilities sidebar (left side.) At the top is a size drop down. Use it to select the size you want to view.

Appears this has to be done for each ViewController.